# inner class access to outer class method, same method names

Tags: java, inner-classes

I got a class and a innerclass

```
01 public class A{
02   void test(){};
03   public class B{
04     void test(){
05       test();
06     }
07   }
08 }
```

Ok, in line 05 id like to access the method test of class A.
But I go into a loop because I dont know how to specify to use the method of class A.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is not a sub class. If you really want to have this structure `A.this.test()` would work.

Comment: @Thilo You are right, its a inner class. sorry 4 that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
01 public class A{
02   void test(){};
03   public class B{
04     void test(){
05       test();  // local B.test() method, so recursion, use A.this.test();
06     }
07   }
08 }
```

EDIT : As @Thilo mentioned : Avoid using same method names in outer class and inner class, this will avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: +1. A probably better solution would be to just change the method names to not conflict.

Comment: In general you are right to avoid the same methodname, but my case is a Freemarker Hibernate Template for generarte delegator-classes from existing instances only.

Comment: I have tried this on my own code and I get 'non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context'. And when I drop the A so it just becomes this.test() (and I something from test) I get 'cannot find symbol'. Is it because I have a return value that causes the error and if so then how do I return a value to an inner function from an outer function

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like that :

```
public class A{
   void test(){
        System.out.println("Test from A");
    };
    public class B{
        void test(){
            System.out.println("Test from B");
            A.this.test();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            A a = new A();
            B b = a.new B();
            b.test();
    }
}
```

You then have the following output :

```
Test from B
Test from A
```

Answer (score 0):

Class B doesn't has to be a so- called nested class to extend Class A just write

```
public class B extends A {
...

}
```

than you can call A's test() like

```
super.test()
```

If you call test() like you do it that's what we call recursive and will freeze until the Day of Judgement

Answer (score 0):

If you make it static you can call

```
A.test()
```

Else you need an instance of A to use in B

```
A a;
a.test();
```