# How to access shadowed Outer class variable from Inner class?

Tags: java, scope

This is not straight forward question. In my case the outer class variable and the inner class setter method's argument name is same. like:

```
class Problem {
    String s;
    int p;
    class Inner {
        String testMethod() {
         return  s = "Set from Inner";
        }
        void setP(int p)
        {
            p=p;  //it will do self assignment
        }
    }


}
```

now I cant initialize outer class instance variable p with `this.p=p` as it indicates the inner class. again I cannot do `Problem.p=p;` it gets an error.
Now how can I assign outer p, keeping the inner Class method `setP(int p)`'s argument the 
same name p ?

Comment: Also check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139160/inner-class-access-to-outer-class-method-same-method-names/12139195#12139195

Comment: @Nandkumar I have just seen, good explanation :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you can/should do it:

```
Problem.this.p
```

Answer (score 1):

Use to refere p to Outer class like

```
Problem.this.p = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Problem {
String s;
int p;
class Inner {
    String testMethod() {
     return  s = "Set from Inner";
    }
    void setP(int p)
    {
        Problem.this.p=p;  //it will do assignment to p of outer class
    }
}
}
```