# Accessing outer class final local variable from anonymuos inner class

Tags: java, variables, anonymous-class

Java anonymuos inner class allows to seamlessly access variables declared on the outer object's method's stack, as long as they ar declared `final`.

But, what if I have a variabe with the same name declared inside the inner class? Is there any way to explicitly refer to the outer variable?

```
public class Outer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        new Outer().call();
    }

    private void call() throws Throwable {
        final String str = "I'm the outer String!";
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String str = "I'm the inner String!";

                // This prints the inner String
                System.out.print(str);

                // So, can I have explicitly access to the outer String?
            }
        });
    }
}
```

BTW, this is different then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346343/how-to-access-shadowed-outer-class-variable-from-inner-class) question, since it regards *local stack* variables.

Comment: does it work, if you use different names for the string reference?

Comment: Even if there were some way to make it work, the code would be unnecessarily confusing and unreadable. The simple, practical solution, though not an answer to your question, is to use different identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the str outer variable inside the run function only up to the point of declaring the new local variable with the same name.
At this point your new variable shadows the other one.

**If you want to use both past declaring the second str, you will have to store it in some other object.**

Your run method gets a private **stack frame** within the current thread stack.
New variable simply gets added to that stack. After executing run, the stack frame is removed.

What you want is to access method parameters outside it's scope (after the new str is added to the stack).

However the stack frame for the outer str is only accesible to the java debug architecture.
Consider this a security concern.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting. `Outer.this.str` certainly does not work, since `str` is a local variable inside a method and not in a class.

In my tests I used the Java 8 lambda notation:

```
final String str = "I'm the outer String!";
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
    String str = "I'm the inner String!"; // error: str is already defined in this scope

    // This prints the inner String
    System.out.print(str);

    // So, can I have explicitly access to the outer String?
    }
);
```

Here the compiler actually outputs an error, saying that the variable `str` is already defined in this scope. In your example though it does not seem like there's a way to access the outer variable.

You just shadowed `str` with the variable inside the anonymous class (which I didn't think would be possible in Java... But I guess it works as long as it's an actual anonymous class).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the variable in the outer class if hidden by a variable in the inner class by doing this:

```
System.out.println(Outer.this.str);
```

**Update:** I don't think you can refer to the variable in the method once it has been hidden. One of the reason to avoid shadowing variables by duplicating names. Another; it gets confusing.

Comment: it´s a local variable inside a method

Comment: As stated it is correct, but I see now it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access class variable, then you may call

```
Outer.this.str
```

But it is not class variable, it is local variable, declared inside of `call` method. And declaration of `str` inside of `run` method is hiding (shadowing) the outer `str` variable.

If you want to avoid hard-to-catch bugs in your code, you should avoid such approach with variables.

**Conclusion**: you cannot refer to **outer local** variable **str** from your `run` method, because there is a variable with the same name, declared inside of your `run` method and it is shadowing outer local **str** variable.

Answer (score 0):

It works, if the field you reference from Inner is a field in Outer.class. If it is a localVariable, the localVariable of the inner-Class will be used.

```
public class Outer {
    private String shadowed = "Outer";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        new Outer().call();
    }

    private void call() throws Throwable {
        final String str = "I'm the outer String!";
        shadowed = "OuterString";

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            private String shadowed = "Outer";

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String inner = "I'm the inner String!";
                shadowed = "InnerString";

                // different reference identifier
                System.out.println(inner);
                System.out.println(str);

                // same reference identifier
                System.out.println(shadowed);
                System.out.println(Outer.this.shadowed);
            }
        });
    }
}
```