# Java: duplicate method signature in nested class

Tags: java

Hopefully this question hasn't already been asked. I've had a look around but haven't found a similar post.

Experimenting in Java I've noticed that there is no restriction on having duplicate method signatures in a nested class, which seems counter-intuitive.

For example, if I create class A containing a method with the signature `int x()` and later add a nested class B containing an identical method, the compiler seems to have no problem with it. My initial assumption was that it would complain that `x` is already defined. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious that explains why this is allowed?

```
class A {
    int x() {
        return 1;
    }

    class B {
        int x() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Subsequently, is there any way to access class A's method `x` from within the scope of class B, or is it permanently hidden by the method `x` of the local scope?

Edit: I appreciate that the core of the question is the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139160/inner-class-access-to-outer-class-method-same-method-names), however, I was more interested in understanding why this behaviour is allowed as it wasn't immediately clear to me.

Comment: Even though they have the same signature, the two methods are totally different, you can think about it like variables within scopes, isolated scopes can have the same name of a variable declared, you may have encountered cases where you used the for loop more then once using the (same) `i` as an index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inner class access to outer class method, same method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139160/inner-class-access-to-outer-class-method-same-method-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Where* a class is defined doesn't matter so much. Keep in mind, in the end you have

```
class A { int x()
```

and

```
class A.B { int x()
```

Two (almost) independent classes. The only relationship that we have here is that any instance of B needs an "enclosing" instance of A to which it belongs (because it is a non-static inner class).

And of course, you can access the "enclosing" A "stuff" from within B, for example using `A.this.x()`.

Comment: `A.this.x()` - didn't know you could do this, very cool. I think my confusion stemmed from the fact that if I remove class B's instance of method `x`, I can refer directly to method `x` in class A without using the trick you mentioned. So by adding the second instance it appears as though there are now two methods with identical signatures.

Answer (score 0):

This should be available somewhere in the `JLS` - but ultimately it boils down to **scope**. Each of them has a *different* scope - thus the compiler does not complain.

Answer (score 0):

Its scope, it's similar to have an instance variable called `foo` and then a local one in the method called `foo` as well.

Its worth reading about [scope in java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Why would the compiler complain? They are two different classes, they just happen to be nested.

Answer (score 0):

> Subsequently, is there any way to access class A's method x from within the scope of class B, or is it permanently hidden by the method x of the local scope?

```
A.this.x()
```

Answer (score 0):

At first method signature is not the combination of return type and method name it is method name and parameters.

if you call x() it will run x() inside the B

A.this.x(); it will run x() in A

Answer (score 0):

Inner class in java can access all the members (i.e variables and methods) including private one, but outer class can not access member of inner class directly.

To access `x()` method of class B inside class A you can either create B's instance and call it or call like this `A.this.x();`

To access `x()` method outside class A you can do something like this:

```
B b = a.new B();
b.x();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using non-static nested class (inner class) then it wouldn't be able to access to x method of B class from other classes. But if you are using static nested class you will be able to access that method from other classes. Example:

```
public class A {

    int x() {
        new A.B().x();
        return 1;
    }

    static class B {
        int x() {
            new A().x();
            return 2;
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.x();
        B b = new A.B();
        b.x();
}
```

I hope this example answering your question... ☺

Answer (score 0):

B is nested inside A. According to scope rules we can do the following:

```
class A {
    int x() {
        return 1;
    }

    class B {
        int x() {
            return 2;
        }

        int xOfA(){
            return A.this.x();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final A objA = new A();
        final B objB = objA.new B();
        System.out.println(objA.x());
        System.out.println(objB.x());
        System.out.println(objB.xOfA());
    }
}
```

that is because B is visible from an instance of A. 
Moreover B can reference methods in the containing class through their full paths.

Answer (score -1):

> For example, if I create class A containing a method with the signature int x() and later add a nested class B containing an identical method, the compiler seems to have no problem with it. My initial assumption was that it would complain that x is already defined. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious that explains why this is allowed?

When you define something in a nest scope which is otherwise in an outer scope, this is hiding.
What is important is that -: **The version of a method that is executed will NOT be determined by the object that is used to invoke it. In fact it will be determined by the type of reference variable used to invoke the method**

> Subsequently, is there any way to access class A's method x from within the scope of class B, or is it permanently hidden by the method x of the local scope?

So as it is clear from above we can access it using class name, eg A.x

Hope this helps!!